# VBA executes one minute, then loops back to a with statement seemingly without cause

Tags: excel, vba, settings, with-statement

At work it worked like 5 times then broke. At home it worked 10 times until it started doing it again: It executes the only with statement but instead of ending the with it jumps back to the beginning code (Set rng) of the with statement.

I'm only executing one line of code and the behavior seems freaKn erratic.

```
With ws
Set rng = .[A3:A7]
rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), 
Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End With
```

Why is it not executing consistently? Shouldn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by "loops back"? Are you stepping through the code with F8?

Comment: Do you have any event handlers set up?

Comment: Yes I f8 through it, no to event handler, it started working again, the code works but after a few runs, as I write more code it breaks on the same spot. Ima go bananas. . . thx ppl

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted which explains the problem you're seeing.